Using the fft command on solution data from ode23
I am solving a system of discretized ODEs using $N=256$ grid points and $L = 256$ is the length of the domain. The spatial grid is equally spaced -L/2:1:L/2-1 Using Matlab's ode23 solver, the resulting solution vector u is a 2177 x 256 matrix in which, per the documentation, each row in u corresponds to a time in the column vector t. That is, u has $256$ components and each row is simply a time slice.
I want to compute the Power Spectral Density $|\hat{u}(t)|^2$ plot it against the discretized wavenumbers $\kappa$ from $-\pi$ to $\pi$.
According to the fft(X,n) documentation,

If X is a matrix, then each column is treated as in the vector case.
If X is a vector, then fft(X) returns the Fourier transform of the
vector.

What confuses me is that I have more than one component in my solution vector which differs than the examples I have read. To use the fft command as desired, do I:

set n = length(t) = 2177 and use uhat=fft(u,n)? The PSD would then be PSD = uhat.*conj(uhat)/n where we divide by n to normalize. Or would I use fft(u',n)?
How would I plot the PSD against wavenumbers?


About your first question, you should take fft from the rows, the n is just the size of the fft output and determines your output frequency resolution, meaning that if you put n=2048, the frequency distance between the output fft results is Fs/2048 where Fs is your sampling frequency. So overall, you should do fft(u', n), where n doesn't need to be equal to your sample size.
For the second question, your output results frequency is in the [-Fs/2:Fs/n:Fs/2) range, dividing by Fs and multiplying by 2pi will give you the kappa axis, [-pi:2pi/n:pi]
